# How to get IsHighlighted to false at a top level menu item?

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem, .net-4.6

Here you can see the inital situation, menu item "Encoding" is highlighted:

[image]

Now I want to get rid of the highlighted state programmatically.
This is working but flickering:

```
WindowState stateOfWindowContainingTheMenu = win.WindowState;
win.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
win.WindowState = stateOfWindowContainingTheMenu;
```

The `IsHighlighted` setter of a menu item is protected and I want to avoid subclassing.
I'm looking for a `C#` window freeze or other solution (though I don't have a `Xaml` solution).

Comment: Your code does not match your question in any way, did you paste the wrong code??

Comment: I clarified my question.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense, you see a flicker because you minimize and then restore the window?  What has that got to do with the highlighting of the menu?  The menu is highlighted typically because the mouse pointer is over it....

Comment: If I play with the mouse sometimes it happens that a menu item stays highlighted without beeing covered by the mouse; highlighted, but not focused; focused is the document. If I minimize and restore the window the highlighting goes away. Alternatively I can press Alt to solve the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad to have finally found the solution: The highlighting disappears if I first focus the `MenuItem` and then the `Window`:

```
topLevelMenuItem.Focus();
windowContainingTheMenu.Focus();
```